# Illustrator - pattern not saved when reopen AI and PDF file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, patterns, swatches

I make several patterns by open jpeg file on illustrator

and drag the photo into the swatches box and 'save swatches' out of it

and then I saved all of them as 'Save Swatch Library as AI'

now I open my working file where there are line drawings and I open my previous pattern library

I apply that pattern as a fill color for my line drawings

I saved my file in 2 version as AI and also PDF(preserve illustrator editing capabilities and create acrobat layers from top-level layers) and I closed the file

but when I reopen both my AI file and PDF file, all the pattern I made in the line drawing disappeared. So my drawing is filled with nothing.

*I tried unchecking the 'preserve illustrator editing capabilities' and 'create acrobat layers from top-level layers' and it works when I reopen. But I still need file that I can come back to edit it

Can you please help me what step am I missing here? I don't want to redo it again every time I open the file.

Comment: AI pattern swatches from jpgs is simply a bad idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong by creating pattern swathes using a jpg or png... 
I also use this method and I never had any issues.

As you save the file and it does not retain the pattern, it could be a bug.

Try to reset the Illustrator defaults.

Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (macOS) as you start Illustrator.

Comment: I wondered about filepath issues - I've seen that really cause havoc with patterns that are raster-based... have you renamed, moved or deleted the original raster image prior to the re-opening of the `ai` file?

Short of that, I agree with LeoNas - reset your prefs.